# Which Queen's Blade episode is when Airi is tickle-tortured my Melona?

Tags: queens-blade

In *Queen's Blade* series, there's a scene where Airi is tickle-tortured by Melona ([YouTube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjCirjCvVVE)).

Which episode does this scene come from?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's episode 3 "Dejection! Airi's Duplicity" in the third "season," known as *Queen's Blade: Beautiful Warriors/Fighters*, which was released as OVAs.

A plot summary from [Fandom Wiki](https://queensblade.fandom.com/wiki/Melancholy:_Airi%27s_Double-Cross),

> [...] Airi returns to the swamp and is confronted by Melona who ties her up and decides to torture Airi by tickling her. [...]